# Can't get each <p> tag for every comment

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape comments of a video , i can easily get everything except for the body of each specific comments using scrapy from this site : https://tamasha.com/v/KGbXY

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

    def crawl_comment(self, video_id):
        video_url = f"https://www.tamasha.com/v/{video_id}"
        # response = self.request.get_request(video_url, proxy=self.proxy, timeout=30, headers=None)
        response = self.request.get_request(video_url, timeout=30, headers=None)
        if response.status_code == 404:
            raise VideoNotFoundException()
        comment_information = Selector(text=response.text).xpath(
            '//*[@class="comment-item"]').getall()
        comment_data_list = []
        for comment_info in comment_information:
            video_id = video_id
            author_username = None
            try:
                author_username = Selector(text=comment_info).xpath('string(//*[@class="user-name"])').get()
            except:
                pass
            author_id = None
            try:
                author_id = Selector(text=comment_info).xpath('//*[@class="user-name"]/@href').get()
                author_id = author_id.split('/')[-1]
            except:
                pass
            date = Selector(text=response.text).xpath('//*[@class="comment-time"]/text()').get()
            body = Selector(text=response.text).css('#commentBox > div:nth-child(2) > div.more-comment > p').get
            id = Selector(text=response.text).xpath('//*[@class="comment-item"]/@data-comment-id').get()
            comment_data_list.append({
                'author_username': author_username,
                'author_id': author_id,
                'date': date,
                'body': body,
                'id': id,
                'video_id': video_id
            })
        print(comment_data_list)
```

I want to get the text of each comment but can't , the code that gets that part is in the body field.

Comment: Are the comments being found? Try printing `comment_information`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't known about the language on the page. But here's the way to extract the comment with CSS selector.

```py
# selector is `Selector(text=response.text)`
selector.css('div.comment-item > .comment .comment-header + p::text').getall()

# explanation of css selector
# >, direct child
# space, descendent
# +, adjacent sibling
```

Here's the output

```
# the second comment seems to be a comment replay
['چه خوب بودن همشون', 'عالی بودن', 'nice']
```

---

BTW, are you not using `scrapy` but only the parser? In Scrapy, `Response.xpath()` will dispatch calling to `Selector(response_text).xpath()` automatically.

If you don't use scrapy but only want the parser. `pip install parsel`, and use `parsel.Selector`. `parsel` is the parser integrated in Scrapy. It can be used independently.